# How to draw tiles with different height?

Tags: graphics3d

I have a random matrix `RandomReal[{1, 2}, {20, 20}]`, whose elements represent the heights of an array of tiles. The cross sections of each tile are square and identical, viz, 10 x 10. How can I draw such a 3D structure? In addition, I need to put several layers on each tile, and each layer has the thickness of 0.5. In this case, how can I draw the whole structure or its cross section? Will partial transparency help?

Here is my code:

```
lambda= 500;
n1 = 1.5; n2 = 1.3;
h1 = lambda/4/n1; h2 = lambda/4/n2;
NQWS = 5;
Wx = 300; Dy = 300;
NX = 20; NY = 20;
h = lambda + RandomReal[{0, 2 lambda}, {NX, NY}];
corner1 = 
  Flatten[Table[{i*Wx, j*Dy, 0}, {i, 0, NX - 1}, {j, 0, NY - 1}], 1];
corner2 = 
  Flatten[Table[{i*Wx, j*Dy, h[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, NX}, {j, 1, NY}], 1];
h1corner1 = 
  Flatten[Table[{i*Wx, j*Dy, 
     h[[i + 1, j + 1]] + k*(h1 + h2) + h1}, {i, 0, NX - 1}, {j, 0, 
     NY - 1}, {k, 0, NQWS - 1}], 2];
h1corner2 = 
  Flatten[Table[{i*Wx, j*Dy, h[[i, j]] + k*(h1 + h2)}, {i, 1, NX}, {j,
      1, NY}, {k, 1, NQWS}], 2];
h2corner1 = 
  Flatten[Table[{i*Wx, j*Dy, h[[i + 1, j + 1]] + k*(h1 + h2)}, {i, 0, 
     NX - 1}, {j, 0, NY - 1}, {k, 0, NQWS - 1}], 2];
h2corner2 = 
  Flatten[Table[{i*Wx, j*Dy, h[[i, j]] + k*(h1 + h2) + h1}, {i, 1, 
     NX}, {j, 1, NY}, {k, 1, NQWS}], 2];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Blue, 
  Table[Cuboid[corner1[[i]], corner2[[i]]], {i, 1, NX*NX}], 
  Opacity[0.8], Gray, 
  Table[Cuboid[h1corner1[[i]], h1corner2[[i]]], {i, 1, NX*NX*NQWS}], 
  Opacity[0.1], Red, 
  Table[Cuboid[h2corner1[[i]], h2corner2[[i]]], {i, 1, NX*NX*NQWS}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

and the following picture is the output structure:

[image: rough surface]

Well, I hope to get one like this:

[image: SEM]

If I just take the top view in my picture, I cannot tell the difference between the tiles of different heights. Any comments?

Comment: "In addition, I need to put several layers on each tile, and each layer has a same thickness of 0.5" ... not clear enough for me (What is a "layer"?)

Comment: I mean, such layers are several different types of materials from the random height substrate, so different colors might be needed to represent them.

Comment: So you're just piling up transparent cuboids. What is your difficulty doing that?

Comment: all right, I got it; probably I need to check my codes.

Comment: A few illustrative pictures from you might be in order...

Comment: I cannot tell what I am looking at [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gQoOe.png).  How is one to read and/or produce that?

Comment: Mr.Wizard, I think that is an SEM image. Such an image looks like the top view of the structure. I hope to generate the similar one. If we take the top view of the image generated by your code, it's hard to tell the difference among the shelves!

Answer (score 6):

Some things that might interest you:

```
dat = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {10, 10}];
ListPlot3D[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Bottom, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
pillar[w_][h1_?NumericQ, {x_, y_}] := pillar[w][{0, h1}, {x, y}]
pillar[w_][{h0_, h1_}, {x_, y_}] := Cuboid[{x - w/2, y - w/2, h0}, {x + w/2, y + w/2, h1}]

Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[0.5],
  MapIndexed[pillar[1], dat, {2}]
}]
```

[image]

```
stack[w_][{hs__}, {x_, y_}] := 
 pillar[w][#, {x, y}] & /@ Partition[Accumulate@{0, hs}, 2, 1]

Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[0.5],
  MapIndexed[stack[1][{#, 0.5}, #2] &, dat, {2}]
}]
```

[image]